# jQuery animation queue

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have an error message that shows when a value is wrong. and using a setTimeout of 3 seconds the message fades out. The problem is when the message shows first time and waits for 3 seconds and at that moment the user clicks submit again the event fires again. the first message fades and fades also the second message.
here is the code of show message:

```
function showMSG(txt,type){
  $('.msg .text').html(txt);
  $('.msg').fadeIn(300);
  $('.msg img').attr({'src':'images/'+(type?'msgDone.jpg':'msgError.jpg')});
  setTimeout(function(){$('.msg').fadeOut(300);},300);
}
```

Please any help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the timeout to a variable and make sure a timeout is not already set before setting a new one.

```
var timeout = null;
```

function showMSG(txt,type) {
    if (timeout !== null) clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('.msg .text').html(txt);
    $('.msg').fadeIn(300);
    $('.msg img').attr({'src':'images/'+(type?'msgDone.jpg':'msgError.jpg')});
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){$('.msg').fadeOut(300);},300);
}

Answer (score 1):

*Edit for clarified question*: In this case you'll need to handle your own timeout and stop the old animation (rather than using [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) that you can't control), [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) returns a timer ID that you can set for 3 seconds (3000ms not 300ms!) and when the next message is triggered, stop the timer with [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Also, you'll want to combine this with [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the fade queue, like this:

```
var timer;
function showMSG(txt,type){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  $('.msg .text').html(txt);
  $('.msg img').attr({'src':'images/'+(type?'msgDone.jpg':'msgError.jpg')});
  var msg = $('.msg').stop().fadeIn(300);
  timer = setTimeout(function() { msg.fadeOut(300); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast replay.the animation is done on the same message. suppose that the first message shown about for 2 seconds. when i click again the message shows the next error and still shown for one second and then fades. as if it the first not the second message. i want to when click again the first setTimeout to be disabled and rebind a new setTimeout with a new 3 seconds.

Comment: @Mohammed - updated, you'll need a custom timeout, a duration or 3000 not 300 for 3 seconds, and a `.stop()` to handle the animation queue as well.